# HttpPost doesn't contain setHeader(String, String)

Tags: java, apache, httpclient

I'm using Apache's HttpClient 4.3.6 in Java and trying to use HttpPost.setHeader(String, string), but getting:

> The method setHeader(String, String) is undefined for the type HttpPost

Here's my code

```
// Create post request
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(GAME_ANALYTICS_URL + GAME_KEY + "/design");

// Encode
String content = gson.toJson(message);
String hashedAuthData = DigestUtils.md2Hex((content + SECRET_KEY).getBytes());
request.setHeader("Application", hashedAuthData);
```

I'm following a tutorial, which uses the setHeader() method. And I googled a bit but couldn't find others having the same problem, but I saw plenty of people using the setHeader() method.

My import is:

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
```

So I'm fairly sure it's the correct one.

Anyone who have any clue what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right version?

Comment: for reference it's here http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html so i'd vote for a version problem, as well.

Comment: Wasn't a version problem. I just didn't realize I needed the core as well. The ZIP comes with 10 different jars, and I didn't want to have to depend on all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I solved it by using both the httpclient-4.4-beta1.jar **and** the httpcore-4.4-beta1.jar.

Seems some of the code is locked out if you don't use the core jar. I tested with only using the core, but then it didn't know what HttpPost was.